# onClick trigger for change color of multiple buttons. JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have 7 buttons in a row. each has a transparent background. I want to click on one of them and its color will change. I press again and it will come back. the same with the rest of the buttons. If the button has changed color, it means that it is pressed. Like a checkbox.
After that, I would like to know which button out of 7 is pressed and which is not.

I use some functions.
This just for container

```
@Composable
fun DaysOfWeekContainer(
color: Color,
content: @Composable () -> Unit
){
 Surface(
     modifier = Modifier
         .size(40.dp),
     shape = RectangleShape,
     border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Green),
     color = color
 ){
    content()
 }
}
```

in this function I use the previous one and put a TextButton in it

```
@Composable
fun DaysOfWeekButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    day: Int,
    //interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource

){
    Box(contentAlignment = Center ){
        TextButton(
            onClick = onClick,
            //interactionSource = interactionSource
        ){
            Text(CalendarData(currentDay = day).currentDay())
        }
}
}
```

In this use 2 previos

```
@Composable
fun DaysOfWeek(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    color: Color,
){

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){
        for(day in 0..6){
                DaysOfWeekContainer(
                    color = color
                ){
                    DaysOfWeekButton(
                        onClick = onClick,
                        day = day
                    )
        }
    }
}
```

So i get row with 7 buttons

```
@Composable
fun MyCalScreen(){

    val stateB = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    val color = if (stateB.value) Color.Blue else Color.Green

    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){

        Text("_")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        if(stateB.value){
            DaysOfWeek(
                onClick = { stateB.value = false },
                color = color,
            )
        }else{
            DaysOfWeek(
                onClick = { stateB.value = true },
                color = color,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It works very predictably. I click on one and the color changes for all buttons. How to fix it? And how do you know which buttons are pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each button should maintain it's state.

```
val states = remember {
    SnapshotStateList<Boolean>().also {
        for(day in 0..days) {
            it.add(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Complete example

```
@Composable
fun ButtonSC(
    days: Int = 6
) {
    val states = remember {
        SnapshotStateList<Boolean>().also {
            for(day in 0..days) {
                it.add(false)
            }
        }
    }
    Box(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){
            for(day in 0..days) {
                DaysOfWeekContainer(
                    color = if (states[day])Color.Blue else Color.Green,
                ){
                    DaysOfWeekButton(
                        onClick = {
                            states[day] = !states[day]
                        },
                        day = day
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```